# android custom drag shadow not visible

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I want to show a custom Textview as a drag shadow. I am extending View.DragShadowBuilder class for this purpose. But nothing is displayed while drag and drop.

This is my custom drag shadow builder class:

```
class MyShadow extends View.DragShadowBuilder
{

    private  TextView shadow;


    public MyShadow(View view) {

        super(view);

        shadow = new TextView(getBaseContext());
        shadow.setText("drag");
        shadow.setTextSize(50);
        shadow.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        shadow.setLayoutParams(view.getLayoutParams());


    }

    @Override
    public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point outShadowSize, Point outShadowTouchPoint) {



         int width, height;

        width = getView().getWidth()  *2;

        height = getView().getHeight()  *2;

        outShadowSize.set(width, height);

        outShadowSize.set(width/2, height/2);


    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {


        shadow.draw(canvas);


    }
}
```

I will pass the textview which is being draggeed to the shadow buider like this:

```
 View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder=new MyShadow(view);
    view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
```

I suspect the issue is with the size/layout param of the texiew is causing the issue. I am not sure where and how to set it.Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to `extend View.DragShadowBuilder`. You can pass instance of your custom `TextView` to constructor.

But keep in mind, that when you are create view programatically, you're not adding it to layout. And `getHeight()/getWidth()` of your view is 0. That's why nothing is displayed while drag and drop.

Well, you have to measure your view, and invoke `layout()` on it.

```
view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
View.DragShadowBuilder shadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
```